# Помогите создать callback, что бы дождаться ответа от сервера

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

Не судите строго – я только начал изучать JavaScript.

Я проверяю права пользователя и если пользователь имеет нужные права, то выполняется код. Создаю `if` в котором вызываю функцию из другого файла js. Проблема в том, что js не дожидаясь ответа дальше выполняет код и поэтому функция возвращает `undefined`...

Вот код:

```
if (verification(localStorage.getItem("client_id"), localStorage.getItem("verification"))){
```

...
}

Код функции из отдельного файла verification.js:

```
function verification (client_id, verification){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/verification",
        method: "POST",
        async: false,
        data:  
        {
            client_id:  client_id,
            verification:  verification,
        }
}).then(function(res) {
    return res;
});
```

}

Как мне сделать так, что бы `if` дождался ответа?

Comment: никак, но Вы уже знаете про `then` )

Comment: если ajax выполнился успешно, то колбек приходит в метод success:         
        `url: "/verification",
        method: "POST",
        async: false,
        data:  
        {
            client_id:  client_id,
            verification:  verification,
        },                                                                                                                                                  
        success: function(res){ //ваш if, res - это то, что возвратит сервер },`

Comment: Используйте [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 2):

Это делается другим способом - не так, как вы это себе представляете. Просто помещаете свой `if` в функцию, которую передаёте в функцию `then`. Вот так:

```
function verification(client_id, verification)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/verification",
        method: "POST",
        async: false,
        data:  
        {
            client_id:  client_id,
            verification:  verification,
        }
    }).then(function(res)
    {
        if(checkResponse(res)) // приблизительно так; res – это ответ сервера
        {
            // ваш код...
        }
    }); 
}

verification(localStorage.getItem("client_id"), localStorage.getItem("verification"));

function checkResponse(res)
{
    // ваш код проверки...
    return //...
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что я неоднократно выполняю данную проверку в разных функциях и на разных страницах, поэтому и захотел создать отдельную функцию для вызова из любых страниц, что бы не повторять код...

Comment: @VaCool, тут также всё просто – переносите свою проверку со входными данными в отдельную функцию и используете её хоть тысячу раз потом.

Comment: так я это и хочу сделать... Выше написал как у меня все сейчас работает без отдельной функции...

Comment: @VaCool, я дополнил свой ответ. Теперь понятно? Функцию `checkResponse` используете хоть тысячу раз потом.

Comment: Спасибо, проверю сейчас